# Как сделать выборку людей старше месяца

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть система списание средств по подписке. Схема конечно тупая, но не я её делал. Есть история операций, в которой есть время покупки подписки. Мне нужно выбрать пользователей, которые купили подписку месяц назад, и создать новую операцию "Снятие за подписку".
Вот так я выбираю пользователей:

`"SELECT * FROM history WHERE type = 'payment' AND date <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)`

Но есть одна проблема как мне исключить пользователей у которых оплата за подписку уже была.
То есть выбирать все строки у которых нет операций раньше месяца.
Для сортировки есть только поле **date** и **uid** - id пользователя.

Comment: Что значит раньше месяца? Имеется ввиду больше/меньше месяца? Что?

Comment: @DmitryD Условие: если последняя запись о подписке старше месяца от текущего дня то условие верно.

Comment: все равно ничего не понятно из условия.

Comment: @DmitryD Допустим я купил подписку на музыку 13.10.2020, плата за подписку должна изыматься каждый месяц. ``SELECT * FROM history WHERE type = 'payment' AND date <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)`` тут отлично работает это условие. Но потом проходит еще месяц и мне нужно получить время когда была совершена последне снятие за подписку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам разрулил

```
SELECT * FROM `history` as h1 WHERE `type` = 'payment' 
AND (SELECT MAX(date) 
     FROM `history` as h2 
     WHERE `type` = 'payment' 
     AND h1.uid = h2.uid) <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я все правильно понял, то:

```
SELECT * FROM history WHERE type = 'payment' 
AND date <= (select max(date) from history where type = 'payment')
```